# Type 'FileUpload[][]' is not assignable to type 'AngularFireList<FileUpload[]>'

Tags: angular, typescript, firebase, file-upload, firebase-realtime-database

I am building an Angular app with Firebase to upload an image to the database and retrieve it from there as well.

### upload-file.service.ts

```
import {Injectable} from '@angular/core';
import {AngularFireDatabase, AngularFireList} from 'angularfire2/database';
import * as firebase from 'firebase';

import {FileUpload} from '../uploadingpage/fileupload';

@Injectable()
export class UploadFileService {

  constructor(private db: AngularFireDatabase) {}
  getFileUploads (): AngularFireList<FileUpload[]>{
        return this.db.list('/uploads');
    }

  private basePath = '/uploads';
  fileUploads: AngularFireList<FileUpload[]>;

  pushFileToStorage(fileUpload: FileUpload, progress: {percentage: number}) {
    const storageRef = firebase.storage().ref();
    const uploadTask = storageRef.child(`${this.basePath}/${fileUpload.file.name}`).put(fileUpload.file);

    uploadTask.on(firebase.storage.TaskEvent.STATE_CHANGED,
      (snapshot) => {
        // in progress
        const snap = snapshot as firebase.storage.UploadTaskSnapshot
        progress.percentage = Math.round((snap.bytesTransferred / snap.totalBytes) * 100)
      },
      (error) => {
        // fail
        console.log(error)
      },
      () => {
        // success
        fileUpload.url = uploadTask.snapshot.downloadURL
        fileUpload.name = fileUpload.file.name
        this.saveFileData(fileUpload)
      }
    );
  }

  private saveFileData(fileUpload: FileUpload) {
    this.db.list(`${this.basePath}/`).push(fileUpload);
  }
}
```

### uploadingpage.component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { AngularFireAuth } from 'angularfire2/auth';
import { AngularFireDatabase, AngularFireObject } from 'angularfire2/database';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import * as firebase from 'firebase';
import { FirebaseAuthService } from '../auth/firebase-auth.service';

import { ItemService } from '../services/item.service';
import { UploadFileService } from '../services/upload-file.service';
import { FileUpload } from './fileupload';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-uploadingpage',
  templateUrl: './uploadingpage.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./uploadingpage.component.css']
})
export class ProfileComponent implements OnInit {

  //for image
  selectedFiles: FileList;
  currentFileUpload: FileUpload;
  progress: {percentage: number} = {percentage: 0};


  constructor(
    private afDb: AngularFireDatabase,
    private _auth: FirebaseAuthService,
    private itemService: ItemService,
    private uploadService: UploadFileService 
  ) { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

  //for image
  selectFile(event) {
    this.selectedFiles = event.target.files;
  }
 //for image
  upload() {
    const file = this.selectedFiles.item(0)
    this.currentFileUpload = new FileUpload(file);
    this.uploadService.pushFileToStorage(this.currentFileUpload, this.progress);
  }

  signOut(){
    this._auth.signOut();
    window.location.href = "";    
  }
}
```

### displaypage.component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
      //additional imports
      import { ItemService } from '../services/item.service';
      import {FileUpload} from '../uploadingpage/fileupload';
      import {UploadFileService} from '../services/upload-file.service';
      import { AngularFireDatabase, AngularFireList } from 'angularfire2/database'; 
      import * as firebase from 'firebase';

      @Component({
        selector: 'app-admin',
        templateUrl: './displaypage.component.html',
        styleUrls: ['./displaypage.component.css']
      })
      export class DisplaypageComponent implements OnInit {

        fileUploads: AngularFireList<FileUpload[]>;

        constructor(private itemService: ItemService, private uploadService: UploadFileService) { }

        ngOnInit() {
          this.itemService.getItems().subscribe(items => {
            this.items = items;
          });
         this.uploadService.getFileUploads().valueChanges().subscribe(result=>{
             this.fileUploads = result;
         });
        }

      }
```

Now while I can upload an image and retrieve it from the database, but I keep getting an error in my terminal showing
`Type 'FileUpload[][]' is not assignable to type 'AngularFireList<FileUpload[]>`
`Property 'query' is missing in type 'FileUpload[][]'.`

Any idea regarding why this is happening?

Any kind of help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Just a little FYI! We landed Firebase Storage support in the last AngularFire release. Should help with your FileUpload service: https://blog.angular.io/file-uploads-come-to-angularfire-6842352b3b47

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not need to use AngularFireList type here,

Create a class as

```
export class Upload {

  $key: string;
  name: string;
  url: string;
  file: File;
  progress:number;
  timestamp: Date = new Date();

  constructor(file: File) {
    this.file = file;
  }
}
```

and in your service,

```
  uploads: Observable<Upload[]>;

  getUploads() {
    this.uploads = this.db.list(this.basePath).snapshotChanges().map((actions) => {
      return actions.map((a) => {
        const data = a.payload.val();
        const $key = a.payload.key;
        return { $key, ...data };
      });
    });
    return this.uploads;
  }
```

and in your component,

```
uploads: Observable<Upload[]>;
ngOnInit() {
    this.uploads = this.uploadService.getUploads();   
  }
```

and change your div using |async

```
<div *ngIf="uploads | async; let uploads; else loading"> 
<div *ngFor="let upload of uploads"> 
<img [src]="file.url" id="image" /> 
</div> 
</div>
```

Comment: I am getting this error : `Property 'upSvc' does not exist on type 'SurveyComponent'.`

Comment: upSvc is the service, you already have there it should be uploadService

Comment: While the terminal is all cleared up, my console shows an error saying `Cannot find a differ supporting object '[object Object]' of type 'object'. NgFor only supports binding to Iterables such as Arrays`

Comment: Which means your response is an object, you need to print and see what you actually get

Comment: place console.log(JSON.stringify(this.uploads)); inside your ngOninit and paste here

Comment: I am getting `undefined`. (The image is getting uploaded though)

Comment: I tried this and am getting: Property 'map' does not exist on type 'Observable<SnapshotAction<unknown>[]>'. off of my service.